# "Selected" button on the attributes window

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, attribute-table, select

I'm following some old instructions that are not up to date with the current version of ArcMap. I'm working on a table that is a layer. When I open it the instructions state that I have to click the 'selected' button on a specific attributes window. What button are they referring to?

Comment: Are the instructions just literally trying to say to click on the attributes window and that's it?

Comment: Can you send through the link / extract of the instructions? What version of ArcMap are they referring to?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue thank you! @KeaganAllan

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that they mean the **Show selected records** button circled below.

[image]

Comment: If this solved it for you don't forget to click the upvote and Accept buttons.